# How to find missing number from an array without using function in php?

Tags: php

I have two array i.e `$arr1 and $arr2` where I want to find missing value of `$arr1` which is not present in `$arr2` without using function like `array_diff(), count(), explode(), implode()` etc. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

code:

```
<?php
    $arr1 = array('2','3','4','5');
    $arr2 = array('1','6','7','8');

    $array = array_diff($arr1,$arr2);
    print_r($arr2);
?>
```

Comment: so what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am simply use `array_diff()` function to find missing value of an array but I want to do without any function @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach:-

```
$missingValuesArray = array();
    foreach($arr1 as $arr){
       if(!in_array($arr,$arr2)){
           $missingValuesArray[] = $arr;
       }
    }

    print_r($missingValuesArray);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/UBS9G

Second approach:-

```
 $missingValuesArray = array();
    foreach($arr1 as $arr){
        $counter = 0;
        foreach($arr2 as $ar){
           if($arr != $ar){
               $counter++;
           }
        }
        if($counter == sizeof($arr2)){
            $missingValuesArray[] = $arr;
        }
    }

    print_r($missingValuesArray);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/Uu6Ob

Comment: in the first approach, you are using an in_array()  function.

Comment: @RajendraSingh  i gave him all approaches what came into my mind apart from `array_diff()`.It's up to him to select any one or discard all

Comment: Yeah, I think Second approach suits user requirement. The first approach with in_array() is also good but it's same like user attempt with array_diff()

Answer (score 1):

Requirement can be achieved by :

```
$arr1 = array('2','3','4','5');
$arr2 = array('1','6','7','8');

$diff = array();
$diff = $arr1;
$arrayDiff = array();

foreach($arr1 AS $value) {
    foreach($arr2 AS $val) {
        if ($value == $val) {
           $arrayDiff[] = $value;
           continue;
        }
    } 
}
foreach ($arrayDiff AS  $k=>$v) {
    if (($key = array_search($v, $diff)) !== false) {
        unset($diff[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($diff);
```

Comment: you are using array_search()